# MWAA Airflow 2.4.3 Slack Connection Not showing

Tags: airflow, slack-api, mwaa

I've got following modules in my requirements file. However, slack isn't showing up when I create a new connection via UI.

In my local environment it is working just fine. I have tried recreating the environment but no luck. I am using MWAA Airflow 2.4.3. Any got any idea what I am missing?

```
--constraint "s3://airflow-zappi-bi-dev/DAGs/constraints-3.7-mod.txt"

apache-airflow>=2.3.0
python>=3.10
apache-airflow-providers-amazon>=7.2.0
jinja2>=3.1.2
apache-airflow-providers-slack==6.0.0
apache-airflow-providers-http>=4.2.0
apache-airflow-providers-common-sql==1.2.0
slack-sdk==3.19.3
```

Comment: Can you edit your question. I think the requirements.txt is mixed with an image you tried to post?

Comment: If you are using 2.4.3, the constraint should be `--constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.4.3/constraints-3.10.txt"`. Are you sure aws airflow is able to install these requirements? You can check this in cloud watch.

Comment: even with this constraint file it's not updating. Also tried removing the constraint file and it didn't work..